# Unicode character "\u1f310" not supporting/showing on notifications

Tags: java, android, unicode

I tried to put the unicode character `\u1f310` on my `string.xml`, but it's not showing on my notifications.

It is possible to show unicode characters having 4 digits. Only problem exist with 5 digit code.
I read other posts, there it says to convert to some other form and put the result. I tried the same but not working.

This conversion isn't even working:

```
\u1f310 => "\uD83C\uDF10"
```

Any method else that satisfy my problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved my issue but which is not in the right method but it was the easiest method for me.

I just saved emojis which I needed in Google keep via my android phone and copied those to Android studio from my PC. Anyway some emojis will display like a square in android studio which will be fine when displaying through app. No need of any conversion also no need of adding any libraries in gradle. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1plnb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

To use the EmojiCompat support library, you must modify your app project's classpath dependencies within your development environment.

```
dependencies {
...
compile "com.android.support:support-emoji:27.1.1"
}
```

[Emoji Compatiblity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat)

Comment: is, `implementation 'com.android.support:support-emoji:26.1.0'` okey..!! my version is bit lower. If it is okey it's still not supporting.